# Core Data+iCloud, change notification inserts and deletes objects in relationships BUT does not update attributes of existing entities in relationship

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, core-data, icloud

In my Core Data model I have an entity that has a to-many relationship (not ordered) to another type of entity. I am also using iCloud syncing with my app.

Now when I add or delete an object in that relationship, the change is reflected on the other device running the app (the objects show up or disappear).

However, when I simply update an attribute of an object in that relationship, the entities do not get updated. I can still see from my NSLog statements that the NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification is recognized, but the entities do not get updated.

However when I close the app, then remove it from the multitasking bar and relaunch the app (and the iCloud store finishes loading), I can now see the changes in the table.

I am very confused as to what is causing this, I need the changes to be reflected as soon as they are imported. Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the staleness interval of your managed object context to something sufficiently low (I set it to 0.0) for it to work. Otherwise Core Data uses the cached values instead.

Comment: Perfect - I looked in many places before I found this very straightforward answer. Thanks!